# Python: split two dimensional array by column elements

Tags: python, arrays

I'm doing a study schedula application, and I want to turn:

```
['gafga',1,'dasd',1]
['gafga',1,'dasd',2]
['gafga',2,'dasd',2]
['gafga',3,'dasd',1]
['gafga',3,'dasd',1]
```

into:

```
['gafga','dasd']['gafga','dasd']
                ['gafga','dasd']
['gafga','dasd']
['gafga','dasd']
```

So the 2nd column became the indexes by the Y axis, and the 4th column became the indexes by the X axes.
How to do that?

Comment: Tell us what you have tried.

Comment: maybe use different words so it will be more readable for us.